# i write a program to create two arry even and odd, as you can see even = chan and odd = le. But i don't know why the result is opposite even vs odd

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
int arr_chan[10];
int arr_le[10];

int i, chan=0,le=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(arr[i]%2==0){
        arr_chan[chan]=i;
        chan++;
    }
    else if(arr[i]%2!=0){
        arr_le[le]=i;
        le++;
    }
}

printf("\nMang ban dau -> ");
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
printf("\nMang chan -> ");
for(i=0;i<chan;i++){
    printf("%d ",arr_chan[i]);
}
printf("\nMang le -> ");
for(i=0;i<le;i++){
    printf("%d ",arr_le[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

}

> why is it the opposite? help me
> result: Mang ban dau -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
> Mang chan -> 1 3 5 7 9
> Mang le -> 0 2 4 6 8
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` will be a compiler error in C#. Perhaps you wanted to tag C?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the index, not the value of array.

Change `arr_chan[chan]=i` -> `arr_chan[chan]=arr[i]`

And `arr_le[le]=i` to `arr_le[le]=arr[i]`

```cpp
int i, chan=0,le=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(arr[i]%2==0){
        arr_chan[chan]=arr[i];
        chan++;
    }
    else if(arr[i]%2!=0){
        arr_le[le]=arr[i];
        le++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Llama I updated the code first then I will update to add the explanation.

Comment: oh no, thank you so much